# Problem with adding google account

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-account, 7.0-nougat, huawei

I'm using Huawei mate 8 with Android version 7.0 and I have a problem with adding Google account and other things. When I am trying to add my google account it immediately goes back to the last screen. I explain better: I'm going to setting and then press Accounts. Then I press on Add account and press on Google. Then the phone goes back to the screen after I click on Accounts. I don't  know if there is any connection, but I also have a problem with Google play app. When I clicking on it, it immediately closes itself without writing any message. This issue also happens on other local apps.